# Error message stating 'Error: object 'date_Object' not found'

Tags: r, function, date

I'm very new to coding and I'm already stumped. I'm working with code that someone else has written, and I need to keep the functionality the same. Here's the error message I keep getting: "Error: object 'date_Object' not found"

Here's the chunk of code I'm trying to run that keeps giving me this error message:

```
sightdate_to_Date <- function(sightdate)  
date_Object <- mdy(sightdate)
is_wrong <- date_Object > Sys.Date()
date_Object[is_wrong] <- date_Object[is_wrong] - years(100)
date_Object
```

Please help! I'm not sure why it isn't working since I'm trying to format, not actually changing any data.

Comment: `mdy()` is a function from the `lubridate` package. Load the package first to make the function available, with `library(lubridate)`.

Comment: You never finish the function definition with an "}" inside the script. Probably a cut and pste error as I see it in the text, but impt, nonetheless. Using proper indenting can help see this easily.

Comment: I did install and load the lubridate package! But thank you!

Comment: Oh, thank you! I bet you're right. I'll try removing the brackets and see what happens.

Comment: Okay, I removed the brackets with the instructional text inside, and ran the code again. This time I get a different error message of "Error: object 'date_Object' not found"

Answer (score 1):

You *need* braces around the function declaration. Without them, this is effectively what R sees:

```r
sightdate_to_Date <- function(sightdate) {
  date_Object <- mdy(sightdate)
} # function declaration/definition is complete

is_wrong <- date_Object > Sys.Date()
date_Object[is_wrong] <- date_Object[is_wrong] - years(100)
date_Object
```

In that context, it should be clear why `date_Object` is not found. If not ... then it would be good to research "scope" of objects; with a little research, I found https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/scoping-rules-of-r.html and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variable-in-r/ which both seem reasonable. Bottom line, variables created/used *inside* a function are not available *outside* the function; the only thing from inside the function that is available outside is the object that is returned, either using the explicit `return(.)` function (often not needed) or the last expression evaluated in the function. If you look at the return value from your call of `sightdate_to_Date(..)`, you'll notice that it is the return from the only expression, `mdt(sightdate)`, and it is returned because the assignment operators (`<-` and `=`) both invisibly return the value assigned.

Ultimately, you need something like:

```r
sightdate_to_Date <- function(sightdate) {
  date_Object <- lubridate::mdy(sightdate)
  is_wrong <- date_Object > Sys.Date()
  date_Object[is_wrong] <- date_Object[is_wrong] - years(100)
  date_Object
}

sightdate_to_Date("2020-02-02") # or whatever object you have
```

Comment: AlexisHaifski, I made a small edit that should resolve the original issue as well. Does this work?